# How to use the result of a query to display a toast message and create a new user in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app a first time logged in user gets to a "Create username" screen where he types in his preferred `username` in an `EditText`. What I want to do is to take the input and see if the username already exists, and if it does display a toast message, if it doesn't then update the displayName of the user.

**Edit:**

The code below is working (used the answer of @AlexMamo)

```
...

// Creates a new username for the new user, which is displayed in the menu but only when the user closes and opens the app again
    public void createUsername (){

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        //Gets the input of the EditText that the user typed in his preferable username
        String usernameInput = username.getText().toString();

        // Here should be a method that creates a new username if the query did not find a matching document or display a toast if the document (username) already exists
        db.collection("User").document(usernameInput).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {

                        Toast.makeText(CreateUsername.this, "This username is already in use.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setDisplayName(usernameInput)
                                .build();

                        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "Success");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

...
```

Comment: `if (userNames)` try this instead `if (userNames == true)`

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AnasMehar If i do this I get the error "Incompatible types. Required: boolean Found: com.google.firebase.firestore.Query

Comment: @Daniel You can use [imgbb.com](https://imgbb.com/).

Comment: I think you need to use query value `ValueEventListener`

Comment: @AlexMamo: please don't refer contributors to post data on external sites. And Daniel: just use the Stack Overflow upload tools. If the image is valuable to your question, one of the more experienced contributors will make it visible.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok puf, got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if a particular username exist in database or not, please change the following line of code:

```
Query userNames = db.collection("User").whereEqualTo(usernameInput, true);
```

to

```
Query userNames = db.collection("User").whereEqualTo("username", usernameInput);
```

So basically you should check is the `username` property holds the user name that is imputed in your `EditText`.

**Edit:**

Seeing that you store as the id of the document the `username`, please see my code below, where you don't need that if statement:

```
db.collection("User").document(usernameInput).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This username is already taken. Please choose another.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: And how do I use this in my if statement?

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question with the code I now have. I deleted all documents in my database to test this but when I type in a new username and press the button, the toast message comes that the username is already in use, even though the database is empty. Then when I create a second account with the same name, it just overwrites the document and its data from the other account.

Comment: You should have tested with the from the screenshot. Try to hardcode the `.document(usernameInput)` like this: `.document("Herbert")`, does it work that way?

Comment: The issue was in another part of the code, where I called this method. Now everything works as expected. Thank you for your time and help!